# Expand environment variables using sed script

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I would like to expand/substitute a variable by its value using sed. Example
File **TestVarExpand.txt** contains

```
Student: $name
Class..: ${classname}
```

In the command line, typing manually:

```
v1="John McGyver"
v2="Molecular Biology CS234"
sed -re "s/[$]name/$v1/" -e "s/[$]\{classname\}/$v2/g" TestVarExpand.txt
```

Console Output (correct):

> Student: John McGyver
>   Class..: Molecular Biology CS234

In the real scenario, I have a lot of variables to expand. So I think of using a sed script as taught in [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html):
Content of **TestVarExpand.sed**:

```
#!/bin/sed -rf

s|[$]name|"$v1"|g
s|[$]\{classname\}|'$v2'|g
```

And test it by:

```
chmod 744 ./TestVarExpand.sed
v1="John McGyver"
v2="Molecular Biology CS234"
./TestVarExpand.sed < ./TestVarExpand.txt
```

Console Output (incorrect):

> Student: "$v1"
>   Class..: '$v2'

**QUESTION**: What is the syntax in TestVarExpand.sed to do the equivalence of sed -re "expr" in command line (double-quote to evaluate variable)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need and export to use variable inside your script and you can use sed inside a bash to have other shell action available in this case.

TestVarExpand.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -e "
   s/[$]name/${v1}/g
   s/[$]{classname}/${v2}/g
   " $1
```

with data

```
chmod 744 ./TestVarExpand.sh
export v1="John McGyver"
export v2="Molecular Biology CS234"
./TestVarExpand.sh ./TestVarExpand.txt
```

result

```
Student: John McGyver
Class..: Molecular Biology CS234
```

Comment: Thanks. Wasted some times today trying various syntax in the *.sed script (I like all the sed expresions in a 1 expr per line). But failed to achieve the expansion of the env variables. Calling sed in a command line fashion with an expression using double-quote the way you did seems to be the only way to use variables with sed.